# Swift - Remove width with condition?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, constraints

I'm coding a social network, which can permit to like and comment pictures.
However, I have a problem with that part ...

If I have one (or more) like and one (or more) comment, it's ok:

[image]

If I have one (or more) comment but no like, the user interface is not very good ...

[image]

I would like to move the button "2 comments" on the left when there is no like. I thought to do that by giving 0 width to the "1 like" button. However, the width it's not all the time the same. If I have 1 like or 12543 likes, the width will be different.

I have no idea about how I could correct this problem. 
Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: you could always use __one__ label for both, and format the text by the current conditions.

Comment: @holex I'm sorry it's not labels but buttons, with action for each button. That is why I can't use only one :/

Comment: Change the like label relationship from `equalTo` to `lessthanequalto`.

Comment: Use a `UIStackView`.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I can't do that given that I don't what would be the value for the equal. As I said, the width is different if I have no like, 1 like, or 12343453 likes :/

Comment: Do not give any width to the label, it automatically adjusted according to the text.

Comment: Don't give width constraint to like button, instead give Vertically Center Alignment with comment button and leading space with parent view. This will adjust like buttons width according to content.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom component that will have a view, and two uilabels as a subviews if the view. the first uilabel will contain the number and the second the title ("comments").
the constraints of the uilables should be as follow:
first table leading == view.leading, first label trailing == second label leading, second label.trailing == view.trailing. view.height == "some constant". In this case the width of the view will be according to the labels width.
Now you should add those custom views to your view. In your case it will be two or one custom components, one for the likes and one for the comments.
add those custom view to tmprorary array and do the following code:

```
var prevLayoutedView : UIView = self
    for (index, customView) in custumViewsArr.enumerated()
    {
        customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: prevLayoutedView.leadingAnchor)
        if index == custumViewsArr.enumerated.count
        {
            customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: prevLayoutedView.trailing)
        }
    }
```

you will need to adjust some constants and compression resistance and hugging priority but this should assist you to solve it

**UPDATE:**
you can use less generic solution and not using a custom component but just using uilable. and then use the same for loop

Answer (score 0):

first easy solution is to keep single label for both if not clickable

otherwise with two labels,

my constraints for two label is,

**1. Constraints for like label:**

[image: constraints for like label]

**2. Constraints for comment label**

[image: constraints for comment label]

```
@IBOutlet var cnLeadingToView: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var cnLeadingToLikelbl: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

assign this outlet in storyboard for leading constraints of comment label then do this

```
if cntLikes == 0 { // temp variable
        //hide the like lable
        self.lblLikes.isHidden = true

        self.cnLeadingToLikelbl.isActive = false // deactivate the leading constraint with like label
        self.cnLeadingToView.isActive = true // activate the leading constraint with view
        self.cnLeadingToView.constant = 15 // give leading space constant
    }else {
        self.lblLikes.isHidden = false

        self.cnLeadingToLikelbl.isActive = true
        self.cnLeadingToView.isActive = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @dahiya_boy said, I had to change the like label relationship from equalTo to lessthanequalto.

I put 375 by default and 0 if the is no like. It was that simple.

Thank you very much everybody !